# 302 Redirection with AJAX post request:

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-302

I'm implementing logout functionality for a web application. I have a function, which is called when the user clicks the sign out button.

```
$.post(window.location.pathname + '/logout');
```

The logout service works only with post.

What happens is:

1. The 302 status is returned as expected with Location: http://myapp.com/logout.html
2. Apparently the jquery ajax call just picks up from there and immediately makes a GET request to said location.
3. The GET request returns the correct html, but it returns it AJAX style, the redirect page is not loaded by the browser

What I would like to happen is:

1. The 302 status is returned as expected with Location: http://myapp.com/logout.html
2. The browser redirects to the given location

Comment: This cannot be done, [in accordance with the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send()-method): "If the response has an HTTP status code of `302`: 1) Set the request URL to the URL conveyed by the `Location` header. 2) ... *transparently* follow the redirect..." The specification does not allow client scripts to observe that a redirect has occurred. -- Anyway, why would you expect an Ajax request to *ever* redirect the page? If you got a `200 OK` response, you wouldn't expect the page to navigate to that Ajax response, would you?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue for me, I was suspecting that this was the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to handle the response using Ajax, then don't use Ajax.

```
<form action="/logout" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="logout">
</form>
```

Comment: `$('<form action="'+window.location.pathname+'/logout" method="post""></form>').submit();` this worked like a charm, thank you!